# Alternative for ViewBox in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Is there any alternative for **ViewBox in Xamarin**, where i can maintain the aspect ratio of my images?

I am converting my Windows Phone app to Xamarin Forms. And most of my screens have clickable images where I capture X Y coordinates of the image parts. I have all my images in **ViewBox** to maintain its aspect ratio, so that i get the same x y positions of image irrespective to screen size / resolution.

I am open to do this with any native controls in **Xamarin.IOS** also.

Comment: As far as I am aware, there isn't an existing control that mimics the behaviour of the viewbox in iOS or Android. iOS uses a system of universal constraints in order to organise controls within a parent container. A similar principle exists for android as well.

Comment: Try Grid. It maintains ratio. There is one catch. It doesn't scale the allocated height properly. See my answers, I have solved it in another answer

Comment: Hi Yuri, May i know whats your another answer for this? i couldn't find any here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [BoxView](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.BoxView/) in Xamain.forms is different from the same name one in WP.

What you need is [RelativeLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/) which is a little complex but flexible. When the app runs on different size screens, the controls will adapt to them according to your constraints.

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <Image BackgroundColor="Red" Source="Icon-76.png" Aspect="Fill" x:Name="redBox"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
            Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,
            Factor=0.05,
            Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
            Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Y,
            Factor=1,
            Constant=20}"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,
            Factor=.6,
            Constant=0}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
            Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Height,
            Factor=.6,
            Constant=0}" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

**RelativeLayout.XConstraint** and **RelativeLayout.YConstraint** locate the X,Y coordinate of your controls.

**RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint** and **RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint** are used to add the width/height constraint to controls.

This image's (x,y) in example is (*(5% of Parent Width)*, 20) which is relative to the parent. And its width or height is 60% of the parent's. Of course, you can set it to be relative to other views via the **Type** and **ElementName** like this:

```
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression 
            Type=RelativeToView,
            ElementName=redBox,
            Property=Width,
            Factor=1,
            Constant=0}"
```

**ConstraintExpression：**

> **Type** – whether the constraint is relative to the parent or to another view.
>
> **Property** – which property to use as the basis for the constraint.
>
> **Factor** – the factor to apply to the property value.
>
> **Constant** – the value to use as an offset of the value.
>
> **ElementName** – the name of the view that the constraint is relative to.

And you can set the **[Aspect](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Aspect/)** to find a appropriate display for your images.

```
<Image Source="Icon-76.png" Aspect="Fill"/>
```

> **AspectFill**    Scale the image to fill the view. Some parts may be clipped in order to fill the view.
>
> **AspectFit** Scale the image to fit the view. Some parts may be left empty (letter boxing).
>
> **Fill**  Scale the image so it exactly fills the view. Scaling may not be uniform in X and Y.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thanks for your reply.  But using RelativeLayout and AspectFit, the image size would always remain the same, it doesn't scale to Screen size. Also, the XY coordinates vary for different screen size. Is there a way to control that? I want XY coordinates to be the same irrespective the size of the image in screen. Any suggestions is welcome.

Comment: @Praddy, I have updated my answer. Use `Aspect="Fill"` to scale to screen size. Also x,y coordinates can be set as a certain percentage of the parent or other view's width/height, see my update for XConstraint.